# How to iterate the string content by new line

Tags: dart

The method `readAsString()` returns the whole content in one string.

For example, here is a source file:

```
#line1 // note, the carriage return here (new line symbol)
#line2
```

How to iterate the content by lines i.e. to get the content separeted by lines like in the source file?

```
await file.readAsString().then(
    (value) {
      print(value); // the whole content will be printed

      // how to iterate the content by lines
      // i.e. process at first `#line1` and so on
    },
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.readAsLines`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-io/File/readAsLines.html):

```dart
await file.readAsLines().then(
    (List<String> lines) {
      for (var line in lines) {
        ...
      }
    },
);
```